Blazor Server Application SQL Server Session State Management
I'm trying to implement SQL Server Session State Management in my Blazor Server Application in .NET 8. I have this SessionDemo component but it does not save the session variable to the database table Session. Here is the code:
Program.cs:
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Load configuration
builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

// Add the session state configuration here
builder.Services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    options.SchemaName = "dbo";
    options.TableName = "Session";
});

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // Consider setting this to true for security
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; // Ensures the cookie is always sent over HTTPS
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
//------- some codes in between to register services, cors, etc.
// I also have to register the SessionService class
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISessionService, SessionService>();

// Further down below I have to declare that I want to use session before app.Run()
app.UseSession();
app.Run();

    

SessionService class:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public interface ISessionService
{
    Task SetStringAsync(string key, string value);
    Task<string?> GetStringAsync(string key);
}

public class SessionService : ISessionService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SessionService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task SetStringAsync(string key, string value)
    {
        var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.SetString(key, value);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public async Task<string?> GetStringAsync(string key)
    {
        var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
        if (session != null)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(session.GetString(key));
        }

        return await Task.FromResult<string?>(null);
    }
}

SessionDemo.razor:
@page "/session-demo"
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<h3>Session Demo</h3>
<label>User Name: </label>
<input type="text" @bind="UserName" />

<button @onclick="SaveToSession">Save to Session</button>
<button @onclick="RetrieveFromSession">Retrieve from Session</button>

@code {
    private string UserName = string.Empty;

    private async Task SaveToSession()
    {
        try
        {
            var session = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
            if (session != null)
            {
                session.SetString("UserName", UserName);
                await Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task RetrieveFromSession()
    {
        var session = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
        if (session != null)
        {
            UserName = session.GetString("UserName") ?? string.Empty;
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Running the code did not create the Session table so I had to manually create it by running this command:
dotnet sql-cache create "Server=(local);Database=AccSol;User Id=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd123;TrustServerCertificate=True;" dbo Session

Session table script:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Session](
[Id] [nvarchar](449) NOT NULL,
[Value] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
[ExpiresAtTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
[SlidingExpirationInSeconds] [bigint] NULL,
[AbsoluteExpiration] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Still, it did not save the session to the database table. What is missing in my configuration? Here is the error I've encountered:
Error: The session cannot be established after the response has started.
